# C++11 how to print out high resolution clock time_point

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

How do I print out a time_point when the time_point is obtained from high_resolution_clock?

```
timestamp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::time_t now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(timestamp);
std::cout << std::ctime(&now) << std::endl;
```

I get the following error message when compiling:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'time_point<class std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, duration<[...], ratio<[...], 1000000000>>>' to 'const time_point<class std::__1::chrono::system_clock, duration<[...], ratio<[...], 1000000>>>'
        time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(timestamp);
```

Comment: You might resolve to an elapsed duration: `duration_cast<duration<double>>(stop - start).count()`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no truly graceful way to do this.  `high_resolution_clock` is not known to be related to UTC, or any other calendar.  One thing you can portably do is output its current duration from its unspecified epoch, along with the units of that duration:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    constexpr auto num = Clock::period::num;
    constexpr auto den = Clock::period::den;
    std::cout << Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()
              << " [" << num << '/' << den << "] units since epoch\n";
}
```

Which for me outputs:

```
516583779589531 [1/1000000000] units since epoch
```

which means it is 516583779589531 nanoseconds (or 516,583.779589531 seconds) since the epoch of this clock on my machine.  On my machine this translates to:  my machine has been booted up for nearly 6 days.  But that translation is not portable.

Ah!  And I note from your error message that you are using [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org).  If you are also on OS X, then we have the same definition of `high_resolution_clock`:  It counts nanoseconds since your computer was booted.

Comment: Thanks for explaining - although the error message is libc++, the code needs to be platform independent (at least for OSX, Windows, Linux), so I'd been hoping for an easy win.  It seems odd that there is not a link between high_resolution_clock and system time, oh well.  I've implemented using system_clock for now.

Answer (score 3):

At least as I read things, the intent is that `std::high_resolution_clock` could be defined as a wrapper around something like a CPU's time-stamp counter, that's simply a register that's incremented every CPU clock cycle.

That's not necessarily the case (and with current systems constantly modifying CPU clock frequency probably a poor idea), but other similar clocks are also intended to be supported.

Bottom line: there may not be a known relationship between absolute time and the high-resolution clock, so it's really defined only to produce durations, not absolute times.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to time_t from any clock time point is provided by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292391/convert-high-resolution-clocktime-point-to-time-t-with-vc141).