# C++: convert chrono::high_resolution_clock to time_t

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I have the following code which works fine:

```
 auto my_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 std::cout << "My Time is " << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(my_time) << std::endl;
```

However, if I replace system_clock with high_resolution_clock like below:

```
auto my_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << "My Time is " << std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::to_time_t(my_time) << std::endl;
```

I got the following error:

```
    no member named 'to_time_t' in 'std::__1::chrono::steady_clock'
    std::cout << "My Time is " << std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::to_time_t(my_time) << std::endl;
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Any idea how to make high_resolution_clock works here? (I am benchmarking some functions, so would like to use high_resolution_clock rather than system_clock) Thanks!

Comment: The example you gave does not match the error message.  The error tells you that you just forgot to add the `chrono` namespace.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make any sense. Are you sure this is the exact error message? BTW, [this seems to work fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f4f5956d4548711)

Comment: Yes, the error is correct.

Comment: system_clock works fine. but not the high_resolution_clock

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a51ace6f480c7b19).  Even after your edit, the error still indicates that you compiled with `std::high_resolution_clock` instead of `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.  Maybe try a clean build to make sure you are compiling all of the right files.

Comment: just built again ... the above is a complied time error, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock still doesn't work

Comment: Ahh, after that last edit the error makes more sense.  On your system, `high_resolution_clock` is aliased to `steady_clock`, which is not required by the standard to implement `to_time_t`.  It's possible that the two are incompatible, e.g. if `time_t` is seconds since epoch, and `high_resolution_clock::period` is smaller than 1 second, then you couldn't represent a `high_resolution_clock::time_point` as a `time_t` without a loss of precision.

Comment: You can convert the two. [Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292391/convert-high-resolution-clocktime-point-to-time-t-with-vc141)

Comment: Conversion to time_t from any clock is provided by this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292391/convert-high-resolution-clocktime-point-to-time-t-with-vc141).

Comment: Conversion to time_t from any clock time point is provided by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292391/convert-high-resolution-clocktime-point-to-time-t-with-vc141).

Comment: Conversion to time_t from any clock time point is provided by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292391/convert-high-resolution-clocktime-point-to-time-t-with-vc141).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your system, `high_resolution_clock` is aliased to `steady_clock`, which is not required by the standard to implement `to_time_t`.  It's possible that the two are incompatible, e.g. if `time_t` is seconds since epoch, and `high_resolution_clock::period` is smaller than 1 second, then you couldn't represent a `high_resolution_clock::time_point` as a `time_t` without a loss of precision.

If you are using this for benchmarking, you can probably skip the conversion to `time_t` altogether.  Just do something like:

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
my_function();
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << "my_function took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 9):

In general, it is not possible to convert `chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` to `time_t`.  It is not just because it lacks a `to_time_t` member function.  It is because:

> There is absolutely no relationship between the time `time_t` measures and the time `high_resolution_clock::time_point` measures.

Think of `high_resolution_clock` as a stopwatch.  You can use it to measure the time it took for some event to happen.  But you can't tell the time of day with it.

On my platform, `high_resolution_clock` measures the number of `nanoseconds` since the system booted up.  If you don't know what time the system booted, there's no way to translate `high_resolution_clock` into a time of day.

`time_t` on the other hand typically measures time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and so *does* have a relationship to the time-of-day.